# Как читать входящий поток в формате XML?

Tags: android, xml

Многие пишут про DOM, а есть более нативные способы?
Спасибо!

Comment: Что вы считаете более "нативным"?

Answer (score 3):

Для Ваших целей подойдет `XmlPullParser` из [Android API](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) либо же использовать какую нибудь стороннюю библиотеку для парсинга xml.

Тут [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/142-urok-79-xmlpullparser-parsim-xml) использования XmlPullParser.

Answer (score 1):

DOM и есть нативный способ доступа к данным в XML.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вариант у меня заработал (на входе имеем String resonse, где tag2 и tag3 вложены в tag1):

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));

        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("tag1");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

            NodeList id = element.getElementsByTagName("tag2");
            Element line = (Element) id.item(0);
            System.out.println("ID: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

            NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("tag3");
            line = (Element) name.item(0);
            System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        return cd.getData();
    }
    return "?";
}
```